# How To Display Color Swatches In Product Page Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to display the color swatches on the magento product page . I have tried from magento admin panel by changing the configuration settings in the system but it is not working

it is coming like this [image]

any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Make you sure that this is **configurable product** and you can take theme support to do this. Only magento developer do this work. In many theme i have seen that color switcher not display even in **rwd** theme display this feature. this is theme issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change settings of Configurable Swatches from magento admin . 
Location :- admin->system->configuration->catalog->Configurable Swatches

Answer (score 0):

For Magento2:
location: stores->attribute->products->(edit attribute which you want)->storefront properties->Used in Product Listing. enable this option and you are good to go, it will show swatches on the catalog product listing page.